# How to edit data in the list (A simple system)

Tags: python-3.6

So, I want to insert a number/data in the list but it invalid syntax.I want to make a system that accepts number and input it to the list then I want it to be edited or modified if I want to.

Here's my code for the modifying or editing:

```
list1 = []
edit = int(input('Enter 1 to edit grade for math, 2 for science, 3 for english: '))
if edit == 1:
    grade1 = int(input('Enter grade:')
    list1.insert(0,grade1)
elif edit == 2:
    grade2 = int(input('Enter grade:')
    list1.insert(1,grade2)
    grade1 = int(input('Enter grade:')
elif edit == 3:
    grade3 = int(input('Enter grade:')
    list1.insert(2,grade3)
else:
    print('error')
    print(adds)
```

Comment: the list1.insert(0, grade1) shows invalid syntax.

Comment: you're missing closing bracket in - grade1 = int(input('Enter grade:') --- add ')'

Answer (score 0):

This should work -

```
list1 = []
edit = int(input('Enter 1 to edit grade for math, 2 for science, 3 for english: '))
if edit == 1:
    grade1 = int(input('Enter grade:'))
    list1.insert(0,grade1)
elif edit == 2:
    grade2 = int(input('Enter grade:'))
    list1.insert(1,grade2)
    grade1 = int(input('Enter grade:'))
elif edit == 3:
    grade3 = int(input('Enter grade:'))
    list1.insert(2,grade3)
else:
    print('error')
    print(adds)
```

Comment: seems you're new to code - your code will work once and will loop out, maybe you'd like to loop it and add entries in one run and exit when ever you need

Answer (score 0):

Formatting is important in Python. The proper formatted Python code is as below :

```
list1 = []

edit = int(input('Enter 1 to edit grade for math, 2 for science, 3 for english: '))

if edit == 1:
    grade1 = int(input('Enter grade:')
    list1.insert(0,grade1)
elif edit == 2:
    grade2 = int(input('Enter grade:')
    list1.insert(1,grade2)
    grade1 = int(input('Enter grade:')
elif edit == 3:
    grade3 = int(input('Enter grade:')
    list1.insert(2,grade3)
else: 
    print('error') 
    print(adds)
```

This however will fail as :

i) The closing bracket of none of the int calls is in place.

ii) For any initial input apart from 1,2,3, the code will fail as 'adds' is not defined.